# C#  Configuration API - чтение версий предыдущих настроек

Tags: c#, .net

Для работы с файлом конфига приложений я использую Configuration API: объявляю свой Section-класс, добавляю описание в app.config.

При этом я использую следующий уровень кофигурации:

```
ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal
```

Таким образом я храню конфиг-файл в

```
Local Settings\Application Data\"Company"\"Application"\version\
```

Проблема в том, что при смене версии место файла-конфига изменяется и прочитать стандартными средствами Configuration API (OpenExeConfiguration) не удаётся.

В Settings API существует возможность для

```
class MyUserSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
```

вызывать метод `Upgrade()`, который позволит считать настройки (`settings`) из старой версии приложения. Я так понимаю, что такую возможность предоставляет `LocalFileSettingsProvider`.

Вопрос в следующем: возможно ли средствами `Configuration API` загрузить настройки предыдущей версии приложения?
Если это невозможно, как "встроить" свою секцию в `Settings API` 
(`MyUserSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase`)?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, в настоящий момент я пришёл к выводу, что реализовать автоматические чтение невозможно.

Идея базировалась на том, чтобы в каталоге

```
 Local Settings\Application Data\"Company"\"Application"\
```

сравнить все версии с текущей, открыть файл конфига предыдущей версии и перезаписать его как новый. Данный алгоритм должен выполняться одни раз при первом запуске приложения. В коде выглядит так:

```
 if (Properties.Settings.Default.CallUpgrade)
        {
            Assembly assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            AssemblyName assemName = assem.GetName();
            Version curver = assemName.Version;
            DirectoryInfo dir = Directory.GetParent(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);                
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
            if (dirs.Length < 1)
                return;   
            Version[] vrs = new Version[dirs.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
                vrs[i] = new Version(dirs[i].Name);
            Array.Sort(vrs);
            if (vrs[vrs.Length - 1] < curver)
            {
                ExeConfigurationFileMap file = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                file.LocalUserConfigFilename = dir.FullName + "\\" + vrs[vrs.Length - 1].ToString() + "\\user.config";
                file.ExeConfigFilename = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath;
                file.RoamingUserConfigFilename = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming).FilePath;

                ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(file, ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).SaveAs( dir.ToString() + "\\" + curver.ToString() + "\\user.config");
                Properties.Settings.Default.CallUpgrade = false;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
```

Алгоритм так и не удалось отладить по причине того, что на самом деле конфиги (**user.config**) лежат не напрямую в каталоге **Application.LocalUserAppDataPath**, как заявляет Microsoft, а по неким суррогатным путям, например:

```
Local Settings\Application Data\"Company"\"Application"_Url_npzl40sahdaapou10uiyprujpbidwoao\version\
```

причём для каждой копии exe-шника происходит создание нового подобного каталога. 
И это неговоря уже о том, что при отладке конфиг сохраняется в каталоге

```
Local Settings\Application Data\"Company"\"Application"vhost.exe\version\
```

Вообщем, чувствую, что придётся пользователям беспокоится самим о сохранности своего конфига. Благо поддержка сохранения настроек в отдельном файле предусматривается разработкой.

Answer (score 1):

У меня была подобная проблема и я решал её так. Я завел строковое свойство, значение которого по умолчанию - пустая строка. При запуске программы я заполнял это свойство каким-то случайным значением. Но перед этим проверял, если оно пусто - то вызывал Upgrade, чтобы вытянуть его значение из предыдущей версии.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.local))
    Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProjectsProfiler.Properties.Settings.Default.local))
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.local = GetRandomString();
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

В результате при запуске новой версии все настройки благополучно мигрируют из конфига прошлой версии.

Comment: Если внимательно прочитать моё сообщение и прочитать код в моём ответе, то видно:
1)я примерно также использую переменную, только она не типа string(ужас - GetRandomString:), а типа bool.
2)я использую не Settings API,а Configuration API,сам веду конфигурационные секции и классы обработчики. Для них метод Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade  не работает.

Но впринципе я уже отказался от Configuration API в пользу собственного сохранения через XML serialize,т.к. со стандартными API очень сложно сохранить объект типа коллекции: надо делать свой typecoverter - временные затраты себя не оправдают

Comment: >>только она не типа string(ужас - GetRandomString:), а типа bool
GetRandomString - это собирательное наименование, оригинальная функция называется иначе. Конструируемая строка используется не только для отмечания факта запуска, она играет роль идентификатора установки.